Laravel reverb auth with sanctum
I have Laravel reverb private channel and when try to listen data not return also when make it as public channel data returned successfully:

In my event I make broadcast with static data but not returned.
Need when broadcast event from mobile app get data to render it .

What is the question...?

need to when broadcast event return data that defined in broadcastWith method

You can try to edit your Echo.js like below ( with authentication ) :
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'reverb',
key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
cluster: 'us2',
forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
enabledTransports: ['ws'],
authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth'
auth:
    {
        headers:
            {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
            }
    }

});
